# HTML embedded PHP note executed when statement is true

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on a basic webform, using php to dislpay error messages and process the data input by the user.
I also use it to echo and ID for html elements to change their color on error:

```
<h3 class="question" <?php if ($error['field1'] === 1) 
{echo('id="red"');}?>Fill in field 1</h3>
<p class="error"><php echo $errormessage['field1'];?></p>
<input name="field1" type="text" value="<?php echo $formfields['field1'];?>" 
maxlength="128" <?php if ($error['field1'] === 1){echo ('id="error_field"');?>>
```

I have a class handling the form and all the errors. `$error['field1']` becomes `1` if field1 is empty, and an error message is displayed by `$errormessage['field1']`.
The problem is, in half of the form the php embedded to `echo` the ID's (red and error_field) works. All the `input` and `<h3>` become red, as defined in CSS for the ID's.
But halfway trough the form, only the `$errormessage` and `$formfields` still work. The other php code doesnt work anymore. It seems to not execute anymore but if as I check all the parameters it should be executing.
Any idea why php is not executing half of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand your problem since I have not access to full source of your file but at the moment I found a lot of syntax errors... pay attention! I have no idea what you are going to do but you can begin fixing your syntax...

```
<h3 class="question" <?php if ($error['field1'] === 1) { echo('id="red"'); } ?>>Fill in field 1</h3>
<p class="error"><?php echo $errormessage['field1']; ?></p>
<input name="field1" type="text" value="<?php echo $formfields['field1']; ?>" maxlength="128" <?php if ($error['field1'] === 1) { echo('id="error_field"'); } ?>>
```